# What is the correct way to use to-infitives?

Tags: infinitives

This topic often confuses me. Sometimes I am not even able to understand the meaning of a sentence. For instance, the sentence:

> "White to move".

You can hear it in chess, it means that the player with white pieces has to make his turn. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the rule to explain this expression.

> "My first movie to watch was ..."

Is this a correct way to use infinitives? It would be nice if you gave me the full rule about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both possible answers could be correct in different circumstances.

If the man speaking was describing a situation *before* he watched the movies, then "My first movie to watch was ..." would be correct.

If, however, he was describing the situation *after* he watched them, the correct sentence would be "The first movie I watched was ..."

Comment: Why is the sentece "I was first to develop something" correct then? I find these sentences very similar